# SwiftUI Modal Environment

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I don't really understand how the environment works when using modals. It looks like the environment is separated for modal views.

I made a quick example using core data and saving an object to Core Data. If I do not pass the environment, then the object does not get saved and I get the following error when trying to save the object:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)

If I pass the managed object context in the modal's environment it works. I commented out the line that makes it work.

Can anyone explain why does this happen, please?

````
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.fetchAllItems()) var items
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var showAddModal = false


    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            List(items, id: \.name) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.showAddModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Add item")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showAddModal) {
                ModalView()
//                    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
//                It works if the managed object context is passed in the modal's environment
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {

    @State var toDoItemName: String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextField("Item name", text: $toDoItemName)
            Button(action: {
                let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                toDoItem.name = self.toDoItemName
                do {
                    try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it by passing the context as a parameter instead of using the environment. PITA!

Comment: @MichaelSalmon you can add it in the modal view environment like that ModalView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext) but it is still more code that it should be, but it helps in case you have multiple parameters in the initialiser and want to cut back on them

Answer (score 4):

It should pass through automatically but **doesn't**.

> "if view A presents view B as a sheet then they don’t automatically share environment data, and we need to send it in by hand. Apple has described this sheet situation as a bug that they want to fix, so I’m hopeful this will change in a future update to SwiftUI." - [Paul Hudson - Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/reading-custom-values-from-the-environment-with-environmentobject)

I don't know his sources, but he seems to know what he is talking about normally.

Comment: As with ios 14 beta 4, the sheet gets the environment of the view it modifies

Answer (score 0):

When you create the first view in **SwiftUI**, the framework generates an **Environment** for it. SwiftUI uses **Environment** to store different system settings like the **color scheme**, **managedObjectContext** and app-specific stuff like default font. All **system settings** and **app-specific stuff** except [our custom **EnvironmentObjects**](https://dreamcraft.io/posts/swiftui-environmentobj-wrapper) are **pre-defined environment values**([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues), you can check the full collection of environmental values).
 One important thing to remember is that **each view inherits Environment from its parent**.

So with the following line of code in your **ModalView**, you are getting the **managedObjectContext** from the Environment of your ModalView that was **inherited** from the view that presents it.

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
```

Also, when you work with Coredata, you should pay attention to contexts, especially if you use multiple contexts.

Tip: If you go to our root view and set all the values that you might need, you will propagate them through your entire app (as values injected in Environment).

**References:**

- [How to modify Environment
  values](https://dreamcraft.io/posts/swiftui-how-to-modify-environment-values)
- [@Environment property

  wrapper](https://dreamcraft.io/posts/swiftui-environment-wrapper)
- [@EnvironmentObject property wrapper](https://dreamcraft.io/posts/swiftui-environmentobj-wrapper)

Comment: This is what the documentation seems to imply, but this is not how it works in practice.  Easy to demonstrate with a simple example and also something that the SwiftUI tutorials work around (in the Working With UI Controls tutorial the `CategoryHome` view passes an environment object into the environment of the `ProfileHost` view it presents).

Answer (score 0):

If I can tag on to this:

when I do add the `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)` My ObservableObject class that I create in the child (modal) will not work correctly.  All vars in the class reset to their initial value each time a call is made to the class's properties or methods.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass view with .sheet, environment objects are not passed so you need to specified your environment object.

Try to open with ModalView() with NavigationLink and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is still an issue for SwiftUI views presented via UIKit (at least iOS 15.0-17.0). However, you can at least pass the existing environment in manually. Future updates won't get passed through, but those should be rare when a view is presented.

```
@Environment(\.self) var fullEnvironment // Define this in a view somewhere and pass it along to your presenting UIViewController

let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: MyView().environment(\.self, self.fullEnvironment)) // Pass it in.
```